# "FOREIGN" is not valid in this position, expecting ')'

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create two tables in a database on MySQL:

Here is the parent table:
CREATE DATABASE FULLMETAL_ALCHEMIST;
USE FULLMETAL_ALCHEMIST;

```
CREATE TABLE CHARACTERS
(NAME VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
AGE INT,
BIRTHYEAR DATE,
BIRTHPLACE VARCHAR(50),
HAIR_COLOUR VARCHAR(50),
EYE_COLOUR VARCHAR(50),
ALCHEMY_STATUS BOOLEAN,
MILITARY_STATUS BOOLEAN);
```

And I want the column NAME to be a foreign key in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE ALCHEMY
(ALCHEMY_ALIAS VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CHARACTERS(NAME));
```

For some reason, this method of adding a foreign key is not working, but this method works:

```
NAME VARCHAR(50),
FOREIGN KEY (NAME) REFERENCES CHARACTERS(NAME))
```

I'd like to understand why my first method does not work. Various websites tutorials have used both methods, but for some reason, only the second one is working for me.

Comment: because the first one is the wrong syntax? which website told you to use it?

Comment: FOREIGN KEY is not an attribute of the column. This is separate constraint, and its creation needs in separate command in CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: @user253751 for example, this one: https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-create-a-table-with-a-foreign-key-in-sql/#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20table,the%20referenced%20column%20in%20parentheses.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL the 1st syntax is wrong. 2nd is the correct syntax for MySQL.

Refer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp